# RDS Cross Region Write Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, latency

What is the best practices for write latency across regions for RDS?

**Use case:** We have users in both Europe and Cambridge with equal read and write access. The RDS is hosted in US-East, thus write latency from EU to US would be slow.

Would it be to have two separate databases in EU and US or is there any way to use a higher tier instance in US to improve write performance?

Answer (score 0):

**RDS doesn't support Multi-Region multi-master setups, i.e. you can't have multiple writer-regions.**

You could have a primary region for read/write-traffic and then a cross-region read-replica in the other region.

Your app would have to send all write-activity to the primary region and could read from the local region (with a delay).

If you want to optimize for cross-region latency, you might want to look at [Aurora Global Database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html). It uses dedicated replication infrastructure with typically sub-second latency.

*As far as I know the only service that allows multi-region multi-master setups would be DynamoDB Global Tables, but that's a whole different database paradigm.*